# Typings for redux / connect like decorator

Tags: reactjs, typescript, generics

I'm trying to create a decorator which behaves like redux's `connect` decorator: Injects some extra props in the decorated component. I'm having trouble with the typings for it

**extra.d.ts**

```
export interface ExtraProps {
  extra: string;
}

// problem must be with this. Intent is to "add" the "extra" prop
// and not require it when the user actually renders it.
export function extra<P>(): (
  Comp: ComponentType<P & ExtraProps>
) => ComponentType<P>;
```

**sample.tsx**

```
interface MyCompProps extends ExtraProps {
  notSoExtra: string;
}

class MyComp extends React.Component<MyCompProps> {
  render() {
    console.log(this.props.extra, this.props.notSoExtra); // ok
    return null;
  }
}

// Decorating it here, prop types should be { notSoExtra: string } 
const MyCompWithExtra = extra()(MyComp);

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <MyCompWithExtra notSoExtra="boring prop" />;
    // error ^^^^^^
  }
}
```

So when rendering `MyCompWithExtra` I get an error:

> [ts] Type '{ notSoExtra: string; }' has no properties in common with
>   type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { children?: ReactNode; }'.

Also when I explicitly specify the prop type like this:

```
const MyCompWithExtra = extra<MyCompProps>()(MyComp);
```

I get a different error on render

> [ts] Type '{ notSoExtra: string; }' is not assignable to type
>   'IntrinsicAttributes & MyCompProps & { children?: ReactNode; }'.
>   Type '{ notSoExtra: string; }' is not assignable to type
>   'MyCompProps'.
>       Property 'extra' is missing in type '{ notSoExtra: string; }'.

How could I type the decorator in a way so that the prop can be ommited when rendering the decorated component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is that if you specify the `P` parameter in the `extra` function, while the info needed to infer it is going to be specified in the returned function call, the compiler will not be able to infer `P`.

You can either use a single function, or, if you want to specify other parameters you can return a generic function from extra.

The bigger problem though is that `P & ExtraProps` will not mean that the properties in `ExtraProps` will not be included in `P`. `P` will contain all properties with the `& ExtraProps` acting more as a constraint on the type of those properties.

To create a type that excludes properties from another type you can use a combination of `Pick` to pick specific properties from a type, and `Exclude<keyof A, keyof B>` to exclude the keys of `B` from the keys of `A`.

```
export interface ExtraProps {
    extra: string;
}
export function extra<P extends ExtraProps>(
    Comp: ComponentType<P>
) : ComponentType<Pick<P, Exclude<keyof P, keyof ExtraProps>>> {
    return null as any;
}

//Usage
interface MyCompProps extends ExtraProps {
    notSoExtra: string;
}

class MyComp extends React.Component<MyCompProps> {
    render() {
        console.log(this.props.extra, this.props.notSoExtra); // ok
        return null;
    }
}
const MyCompWithExtra = extra(MyComp);
let s = <MyCompWithExtra notSoExtra="boring prop" />;
```

**Note** If you want to allow the user to optionally specify `extra`, you can return `ComponentType<Pick<P, Exclude<keyof P, keyof ExtraProps>>> & Partial<ExtraProps>` instead.